# Are There Other Ways For Humans to Cool Down Besides Sweating?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, humans

It's been said that sweating is the human way of shedding off excess heat.  But to do that requires a loss of water, which makes the overall sensation miserable and uncomfortable.

Are there other, drier ways for humans to prevent overheating without feeling uncomfortably damp?  (Larger ears excluded--that's more of an elf thing.)

Comment: This is physiology or biology, not world building.

Comment: See the [Wikipedia page on thermoregulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoregulation), including a list of other methods.

Comment: It's on-topic here because, as the Mods have said, questions about the real world are fair game here at WB.SE.

Comment: @L.Dutch It would certainly be on-topic at [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), and the OP might get a more in-depth answer if he asked there, but that doesn't make it off-topic here when this could be applied to a fictional species (like elves, for instance).

Comment: Does BSE really accept hypothetical "what if" questions, especially ones which seek to alter such fundamental property of human physiology? Any answer would be just wild speculation from scientific viewpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Sweating is, by far, the most effective option available to humans for cooling off. It's only available because we have no fur coat to speak of; if we had any fur to speak of, sweating would become several times less efficient and would likely cause other issues. Dogs, for instance, stick their tongues out and start panting when overheated; moisture evaporates off their tongues and steals energy in doing so, cooling them off, but full-body sweating magnifies the surface area (and thus the cooling effect) in comparison.

It's worth noting that humans, for all our other weaknesses in nature, are virtually unmatched in endurance in the animal kingdom, due in large part to our ability to sweat and shed excess heat so efficiently and quickly. If you want to replace sweating with something else, it will almost certainly be less effective. You can forget humans running marathons, or indeed much of anything that requires hours of hard labor on end; eight-hour work shifts would become ludicrous for demanding physical tasks. Warfare would become very different, especially in pre-industrial times where heavy armor was common; plate mail would be suicidal to don when you would basically cook yourself alive after thirty minutes of fighting, and even chain mail would be problematic, plus the matter of how much more quickly we would tire and become unable to effectively fight. The implications are endless, and you'd best think them through carefully before you try making such a fundamental change to humans.

Comment: I believe ostriches might be superior even to humans in the field of endurance, as they are virtually impossible to persistence hunt. Cursorialism plus air sacs equals one hell of a marathoner.

Comment: The "fur coat" part is wrong.  Horses are covered with hair (and some breeds can get quite furry in the winter), yet they sweat quite as much as humans.  WRT endurance, sled dogs (and their wolf ancestors) have humans beat hands down (or should that be paws down?): https://www.adn.com/iditarod/article/what-makes-iditarod-dogs-perfect-endurance-athletes/2012/03/16/  But of course they do this in an environment in which it is easy to shed heat.

Comment: @jamesqf I'm referring to humans who are physically in good condition (to reflect what would come about in nature), as opposed to the average urban citizen. Wolves, granted, are pretty good for endurance, but they hunt in shorter chases; they don't tend to run animals down to exhaustion. Your point about horses is true (note how they are an exception, not the general rule), but they still overheat a lot more easily than humans: they sweat, yes, but their hair gets in the way of its effectiveness.

Comment: If sweating is efficient, why does it always feel miserable and you spend too much time keeping dry?

Comment: @JohnWDailey "Efficient" refers to how well it does the task at hand: cooling off, in this instant. Almost everything has a tradeoff of some sort, which in the case of sweating would be a little physical discomfort (and yes, a hypothermia risk if you're pouring sweat in subzero temperatures without proper protection, but then you're just being an idiot). By modern standards, yes, being sticky with sweat is miserable; having clothes on certainly makes it more so, since now your clothes are stuck to you. Is life-threatening heat stroke a preferable outcome to that inconvenience? I think not.

Comment: @Palarran: I'm referring to humans in good condition, too, say someone who runs 100 mile ultramarathons vs sled dogs who run over 10 times as far.  WRT hunting, neither to humans tend to run prey to exhaustion - and when they do, it's more often as teams rather than individuals.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a human, no, there are no other options. We are literally **built** to cool off via sweating.

But if you need to build a variation of our species on a parallel Earth, the answer is: fur. Fur keeps us all nice and insulated, though we'd still be sweating a tad, and we'd need to bathe more frequently to stay cleaner

Answer (score 0):

If your willing to place a lot more capillaries under the surface for your throat and mouth, panting is a decent way to remove some excess heat. Problem is that panting is nowhere near as effective as sweating as removing heat while multitasking. With human sweating, they can cool off while running, which is a huge advantage when hunting or fleeing.

If you're okay with losing some more multitasking while cooling off, then relying on the environment to disperse heat is also an option. Have the humans sitting out the hottest part of the day in the shade or in water, and sunning themselves when the weather gets cooler. This is a massive downgrade in terms of planning out your day, but it does save a lot of energy, so you get to eat less food to keep going. This system is what reptiles use, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, humans do cool through other means, our skins radiate heat, air convection cools even dry skin, and we also shed heat to the air we breath. But sweating, [evaporative cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler#Physical_principles), is a *far* more efficient method, for us hairless apes anyway, of dumping heat into the environment. Evaporative cooling has it's limits though, for example as the humidity of your surrounding environment increases it becomes less and less useful until at 100% [relative humidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_humidity) it stops working altogether. Primates are extremely, almost uniquely in fact, dependent on the efficiency of sweating as a cooling method so in a situation where humans are generating a lot of heat, as through manual labour, they need to sweat.